# spark structured streaming dataframe/dataset apply map, iterate record and look into hbase table using shc connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using structured streaming with Spark 2.1.1 Needs to construct the key from coulmns available in streaming dataframe(kafka source) and get the hbase table data in dataframe(static) using shc spark hbase connector. Then apply business logic using both dataframes.
        Planning to construct key from iterating records in streaming dataframe, and for each record after constructing key look into hbase table, get the dataframe using shc connector, then apply some business logic using both dataframes. then send response data to kafka topic.

structured streaming with Spark 2.1.1, kafka data source, shc spark hbase connector

```
  val StreamingDF= spark.readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBroker)
          .option("subscribePattern", kafkaReqTopic)
          .load()


    val responseDF = StreamingDF.mapPartitions(rowIter => rowIter.map {
          row =>
            import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
            def catalog = s"""{
            |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"abchbasetable"},
            |"rowkey":"abchbasetablerowkey",
            |"columns":{
            |"rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"abchbasetablerowkey", "type":"string"},
            |"col1":{"cf":"topo", "col":"col1", "type":"string"}
            |}
        |}""".stripMargin

            def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
              spark.sqlContext
                .read
                .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> cat))
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
                .load()
            }

            val staticDF = withCatalog(catalog)
            staticDF.show(10, false)            

        })

 val kafkaOutput = abc.responseDF
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBroker)
          .option("topic", topicname)
          .option("checkpointLocation", "/pathtocheckpoint")`enter code here`
          .start()
```

planned to get the static dataframe from hbase and append coulmns to streaming dataframe

Comment: What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: Hi Jacek, inside map function iam not able to create another dataframe(read from hbase using shc connector)  code:- StreamingDF.mapPartitions(rowIter => rowIter.map {      using spark hbase connector create dataframe for hbase table     })

Comment: It's not possible. You're in a dream and you want another dream. Remember that - it's a movie :) DataFrames don't allow for such "flexibility". You have to use `DataStreamWriter.foreach` and `collect` the dataframe inside the method.